# How do I check my Xbox account balance online?

Tags: xbox-network

I used to have points on my account and I want to check the remaining credit without using my Xbox but can't seem to find the xbox.com page. Where is it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## **https://commerce.microsoft.com/PaymentHub**

After you log in, it'll be under "Payment Options" next to the Microsoft logo. And [here](https://support.xbox.com/en-US/my-account/microsoft-account/check-your-microsoft-account-balance) are the console directions.